# Jar codes throw subclasses, but xamarin binding codes throw baseclasses

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Java codes in Jar :

```
public class FatherClass
{
    public void throwChildAClassException()
    {
        throw new FatherClass.ChildAClassException();
    }

    public class ChildAClassException extends RuntimeException
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }

    public class ChildBClassException extends RuntimeException
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }
}
```

in Xamarin:

When I call the method `ThrowChildAClassException()`, and it throws the baseclass as `RuntimeException`.

↓↓↓ code ↓↓↓

```
try
{
    new FatherClass().ThrowChildAClassException()
}
catch(ChildAClassException childAE)
{
    // debugged but does not reach here
}
catch(ChildAClassException childBE)
{
    // no invoking
}
catch(RuntimeException e)
{
    // debugger approaches here. Isn't it wrong or a bug?
}
```

So, how can I get the subclass like `ChildAClassException`?
Thx, all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by me ...

```
try
{
    new FatherClass().ThrowChildAClassException()
}
catch(RuntimeException e)
{
     // Android.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast<ChildAClassException>(e);
     // Android.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast<ChildBClassException>(e);

    string currentExceptionSimpleName = e.Class.SimpleName;
    string classChildAClassExceptionSimpleName = typeof(ChildAClassException).Name;
    string classChildBClassExceptionSimpleName = typeof(ChildBClassException).Name;

    if(currentExceptionSimpleName == classChildAClassExceptionSimpleName)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if(currentExceptionSimpleName == classChildBClassExceptionSimpleName)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```